# Background image over a background color on email

Tags: html, css, email, background

Creating an email template with a table containing an image as background, I wonder whether it's possible to get a substitute background color whenever the image is not displayed (by default on most of the email platforms).

I have tried the following:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background: #005a84 url(http://xxxx/email-bckg.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat">
```

But testing on Outlook, even if I click on "load images" then, the background color property override the background image.

Any idea?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook 2003/2007 (Desktop Version) are unable to show `background-images`
use http://backgrounds.cm/ instead

Comment: That works well under Outlook - meaning that the bg color/image displays properly. However, all my properties within the table are gone. The styling from my paragraphs within the table gets stripped out. Any idea why?

Comment: put your content in `<div></div>`. It will work, I've tested it by myself. :)

Comment: It works on browser (IE included) and several email clients but not Outlook 2007 for some reason.

Could you link up your code so I can compare to double check I have not missed anything? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your style:

```
style="
background: url(http://xxxx/email-bckg.jpg); 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-color: #005a84;"
```

You just need to remove the color code from "background" and add background-color.

That way you always have the background color set, but if the image can be shown, it will overlay the background color.